# Count the numbers after each comma and also the number before first comma in python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a dataframe with multiple columns and one of the columns **book_no** has multiple numbers separated by comma.
I want to count those and assign it to a columns called as **total_books_by_each_user**.
Example:

```
data['book_no']
1,2,3,5,10,11
```

Any possible solution to do this?

I tried this, but didn't work.

```
data.book_no.count(",") + 1
```

book number is of object type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing the [`str`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.html) accessor, which allows you to apply string operations in a vectorized manner:

```
df.book_no.str.count(',').add(1)

0    3
1    3
Name: book_no, dtype: int64
```